# How to upload a big file (4 Go video for example) to a bucket with python?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, file-upload, google-cloud-storage, fastapi

I need to find a solution to upload large videos in a Google Cloud Platform bucket from an API (fastAPI/python) without leaving a POST request opened infinitely. I already did some researches and the only solution that came out was dividing the video to upload it chunk by chunk into the bucket. I wonder if there are other solutions or not please?

Comment: From where does the big file come? Is it a user upload? Does it generated by your app and you need to upload it to Cloud Storage?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please be aware this is not a code-writing or tutoring service. We can help solve specific, technical problems, not open-ended requests for code or advice. Please edit your question to show what you have tried so far, and what specific problem you need help with. See the [How To Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for details on how to best help us help you.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: It is a user upload, so the user uses a front from where they select the file and it has to uploaded by the API to Cloud storage